# Recharts Y-Axis interval issue

Tags: reactjs, intervals, recharts, yaxis

I am using [Recharts Library](https://recharts.org/en-US/) for the graph in the ReactJS. There is one strange issue of setting intervals for the Y-Axis. There are few options available "preserveStart" | "preserveEnd" | "preserveStartEnd" | Number. For me, this is not working.

I have attached a couple of screens to showcase what I am expecting and what I get.

**Expectation**
[image: Expectation]

**Actual**
[image: Actual]

**Note: Due to the confidentiality of the project, I am not allowed to put the code here. Please let me know if more information is required.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to see a given number of ticks on the Y-Axis, you need to use the props `tickCount` - the number of ticks to show (by default, it's 5).

So you're Y-Axis should simply look like this:

```js
<YAxis tickCount={10} />
```

The `interval` props allows you to show only a part of the ticks; '0' would show all, '1' would show half (1 every 2 ticks), etc.